# How to find a Jordan canonical form?

Tags: linear-algebra

Dear Linear Algebra Experts,

I am preparing for my exams and currently stuck with following problem. The following question may be trivial for you, but I don't know how to solve it. I would really appreciate your help.

The linear transformation $d/dt : x(t) → x^\prime(t)$ acting on the vector
space of all polynomials with degree at most 3 has the basis representation
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 &0 &0 \\
0 &0 &2 &0 \\
0 &0 &0 &3 \\
0 &0 &0 &0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
in the basis $T = \left\{1, t, t^2, t^3\right\}$. What is the Jordan canonical form of this matrix?

Comment: The Jordan canonical form is what you have but replace all non zero entries by ones. Let $P = \operatorname{diag}(1,1,{1 \over 2}, {1 \over 6})$ and take $P^{-1} A P$.

Comment: You just need to scale the columns, but carefully.

Comment: Choose instead the basis $T=\{ 1,t,\frac{1}{2}t^2,\frac{1}{6}t^3\}$.

Comment: thank you everyone for your replies.